# Dead letter strategy - ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: message-queue, activemq-artemis

I am designing a mechanism to handle a message when it is not received by the consumer.

I use ActiveMQ Artemis. I want to configure the broker in such a way that when messages fail to deliver several times they go to DLQ like in [this documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/undelivered-messages.html). After unsuccessful attempts, messages will be thrown into my own DLQ address, but here my question arises.

I want the message to be sent back in the initial queue after 5 minutes. Message redirection is not really a problem, it is mentioned in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/diverts.html).

But how can I set the message to be sent with a 5 minute delay? I see that there is such a possibility in [this documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/scheduled-messages.html), but it is supported from the application level and I would like to set it from `broker.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

The specific behavior you're looking for isn't supported, and I'm not sure it makes sense for it to actually be supported either. If the messages sent to the dead-letter address just need to be sent back to the original address after 5 minutes then I would recommend you simply configure a redelivery delay of 5 minutes.

Aside from that you could create a simple listener on your dead-letter queue that consumes any message and then sends it back to the original address with a scheduled delivery delay as described in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, but what about previous messages? They will be waiting for this time. I want them to be redirected to DLQ after an unsuccessful attempt, and then sent to the initial queue, but at its end.

Comment: What do you mean that "previous messages...will be waiting for this time"? Redelivery delay should not block messages from being consumed during the delay.